# INSERT INTO a created table throws an error

Tags: sql-server, insert-into

The following code shows an error on the SELECT statement in line 2.

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 
             FROM Table1 A
             LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id = B.Id) AB
   SELECT Column1, Column2
   FROM ExtraData C
```

What I'm trying to do here is - I have 2 tables, A and B, that need to be joined (to make the table AB) and then to this joined table I have to add a few extra rows which are present in C

If I create a temp table for the table AB before the `INSERT INTO` it seems to work fine.

Is there such a restriction on `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes you cannot do this in `Sql Server`. I don't know which RDBMS supports this form. As you mentioned you need to create `temp` table with two columns

Comment: You are missing the table name in the `insert` statement.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gordon - Have I not named the new table at the end of select statement as AB?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in SQL Server. I don't know what RDBMS supports this syntax, or even what you expect as output.

There are two ways to insert data into a temp table. You already discovered the first which is `CREATE TABLE #AB (...)` then `INSERT INTO #AB`.

The second way is to use `SELECT ... INTO`:

```
SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 
INTO #AB
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.Id = B.Id

-- Now that #AB is defined, you can use INSERT INTO to add additional data
INSERT INTO #AB (Column1, Column2)
   SELECT Column1, Column2
   FROM   ExtraData C
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a table called `AB`, using `select into`:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
INTO AB
FROM ExtraData C;
```

It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do, though.

If that is the case, then use `union all`:

```
SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 
INTO AB
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN
     Table2 B
     ON A.Id = B.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM ExtraData C;
```

If you already have the table defined, then do:

```
INSERT INTO AB(column1, column2)    
    SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 
    FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN
         Table2 B
         ON A.Id = B.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM ExtraData C;
```

Comment: I have 2 tables that need to be joined ( to make the table AB) and then to this joined table I have to add a few extra rows which are present in C

Comment: Your sql up top doesn't show what you're selecting into. That's the syntax error on line 2 I'm guessing. Other than that you just need to add union between the two data sources as in this example

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.Id = B.Id
UNION
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM ExtraData C
```